# What does this error mean? Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fbo

I am new to Java and new to Android Studio. I am following a Udemy tutorial and I am creating a "Guess the Celebrity" app. Every app I have created up until now has worked flawlessly. The unbinding FBO error pops up every time I run the emulator and the "Guess the Celebrity" application runs; however, it does not display the data it is supposed to receive from an external source. The tutorial uses a much older version of Android Studio and I am using Android Studio 3.5. Is there extra code required for the newer version? And yes, I did put the Internet Permission code under AndroidManifest.xml. I have not been able to get data from external sources on three different applications and this error occurs in all three.

As I'm not even sure what this error means, I'm not 100% sure what I should be trying. I did change some settings in my anti-virus software (Bitdefender) to give Android Studio further permissions. I also tried 
      con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla");       This got rid of the unbinding FBO error, but overall still did not get the necessary data from the external source. Here's my code:

```
    package com.example.guessthecelebrity;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ArrayList<String> celebURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> celebNames = new ArrayList<String>();
       int chosenCeleb = 0;
       String[] answers = new String[4];
       int locationOfCorrectAnswer = 0;
       ImageView imageView;
       Button button0;
       Button button1;
       Button button2;
       Button button3;

       public void celebChosen(View view) {
        if (view.getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(locationOfCorrectAnswer))) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong! It was" + celebNames.get(chosenCeleb),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

newQuestion();
}



public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return myBitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}

public void newQuestion () {
    try {

    Random rand = new Random();
    chosenCeleb = rand.nextInt(celebURLs.size());

    ImageDownloader imageTask = new ImageDownloader();

    Bitmap celebImage = imageTask.execute(celebURLs.get(chosenCeleb)).get();

    imageView.setImageBitmap(celebImage);

    locationOfCorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(4);

    int incorrectAnswerLocation;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswer) {
            answers[i] = celebNames.get(chosenCeleb);
        } else {
            incorrectAnswerLocation = rand.nextInt(celebURLs.size());

            while (incorrectAnswerLocation == chosenCeleb) {
                incorrectAnswerLocation = rand.nextInt(celebURLs.size());
            }

            answers[i] = celebNames.get(incorrectAnswerLocation);
        }
    }

    button0.setText(answers[0]);
    button1.setText(answers[1]);
    button2.setText(answers[2]);
    button3.setText(answers[3]);
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;

    try {

        result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();

        String[] splitResult = result.split("<div class=\"listedArticles\">");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("img src=\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

        while (m.find()) {
            celebURLs.add(m.group(1));
        }

        p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
        m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

        while (m.find()) {
            celebNames.add(m.group(1));
        }

        newQuestion();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Logcat when I run the app

2019-09-10 15:24:33.133 2018-2018/? D/DevicePolicyManager: updateSystemUpdateFreezePeriodsRecord

2019-09-10 15:24:33.136 2018-2018/? D/ConditionProviders.SCP: onReceive android.intent.action.TIME_SET

2019-09-10 15:24:33.138 2018-2018/? D/ConditionProviders.SCP: evaluateSubscriptionLocked cal=ScheduleCalendar[mDays={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, mSchedule=ScheduleInfo{days=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], startHour=22, startMinute=0, endHour=7, endMinute=0, exitAtAlarm=true, nextAlarm=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 (0)}], now=Tue Sep 10 15:24:33 EDT 2019 (1568143473136), nextUserAlarmTime=Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 (0)

2019-09-10 15:24:33.138 2018-2018/? D/ConditionProviders.SCP: notifyCondition condition://android/schedule?days=1.2.3.4.5.6.7&start=22.0&end=7.0&exitAtAlarm=true STATE_FALSE reason=!meetsSchedule

2019-09-10 15:24:33.139 2018-2018/? D/ConditionProviders.SCP: Scheduling evaluate for Tue Sep 10 22:00:00 EDT 2019 (1568167200000), in +6h35m26s864ms, now=Tue Sep 10 15:24:33 EDT 2019 (1568143473136)

2019-09-10 15:24:33.144 2018-2044/? I/UsageStatsService: Time changed in UsageStats by 223 seconds

2019-09-10 15:24:33.144 2018-2044/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk

2019-09-10 15:24:33.169 2018-2146/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, application is not in focus neither is a system service for user 0

2019-09-10 15:24:33.177 11972-11972/? I/AlarmClock: AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.TIME_SET

2019-09-10 15:24:33.170 2018-2146/? E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, application is not in focus neither is a system service for user 0

2019-09-10 15:24:33.177 2018-3755/? W/ProcessStats: Tracking association SourceState{35cce84 com.google.android.gms.persistent/10096 ImpFg #47674} whose proc state 2 is better than process ProcessState{f3b5062 com.google.android.gms/10096 pkg=com.google.android.gms (sub)} proc state 3 (23 skipped)

2019-09-10 15:24:33.184 11972-21483/? I/AlarmClock: Connected Dock: null

2019-09-10 15:24:33.185 11972-21483/? I/AlarmClock: Removing AlarmClockInfo

2019-09-10 15:24:33.188 2176-2442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbfe460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebc21c60)

2019-09-10 15:24:33.189 11972-11972/? I/AlarmClock: DigitalAppWidgetProvider processing Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_SET flg=0x25200010 cmp=com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.alarmclock.DigitalAppWidgetProvider }

2019-09-10 15:24:33.205 10700-21727/? I/SystemUpdate: [Installation,ReceiverIntentOperation] Received intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_SET flg=0x25200010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver }.

2019-09-10 15:24:33.220 10700-21668/? I/SystemUpdate: [Execution,InstallationEventIntentOperation] Handling event of type 6.

2019-09-10 15:24:33.228 10700-21732/? I/SystemUpdate: [Execution,ExecutionManager] Action finished-execution executed for 0.00 seconds.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.230 3093-3093/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing

2019-09-10 15:24:34.272 2018-3755/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.guessthecelebrity appid=10133 user=0: from pid 21873

2019-09-10 15:24:34.272 2018-3755/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 21661:com.example.guessthecelebrity/u0a133 (adj 0): stop com.example.guessthecelebrity

2019-09-10 15:24:34.273 2018-3755/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{e5a1ac2 u0 com.example.guessthecelebrity/.MainActivity t64 f}: app died, no saved state

2019-09-10 15:24:34.281 2018-3755/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.289 2018-3755/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:2018_16 identical 18 lines

2019-09-10 15:24:34.318 1777-1777/? I/Zygote: Process 21661 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.333 1792-1792/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496

2019-09-10 15:24:34.391 2018-3755/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.guessthecelebrity/.MainActivity} from uid 2000

2019-09-10 15:24:34.398 2018-2040/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.503 2621-3201/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0b1a5a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0b0f720)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.540 2018-2018/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } U=0: not found

2019-09-10 15:24:34.540 2018-2018/? W/RemoteAppPredictionService: could not bind to Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } using flags 67108865

2019-09-10 15:24:34.540 2018-2968/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:2018_10 identical 8 lines

2019-09-10 15:24:34.541 2018-2968/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.544 10528-10561/? W/SessionLifecycleManager: Handover failed. Creating new session controller.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.553 1777-1777/? D/Zygote: Forked child process 21888

2019-09-10 15:24:34.553 2176-2442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbfe460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebc21c60)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.557 21888-21888/? I/essthecelebrit: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.562 2018-2046/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 21888:com.example.guessthecelebrity/u0a133 for activity {com.example.guessthecelebrity/com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity}

2019-09-10 15:24:34.570 21888-21888/? E/essthecelebrit: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

2019-09-10 15:24:34.571 21888-21888/? W/essthecelebrit: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

2019-09-10 15:24:34.585 2018-3948/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.590 2018-3948/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:2018_1A identical 28 lines

2019-09-10 15:24:34.590 2018-3948/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.592 2018-2040/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.593 2018-2040/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) android.anim identical 8 lines

2019-09-10 15:24:34.593 2018-2040/? W/InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.599 2018-2044/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.example.guessthecelebrity/.MainActivity: +146ms

2019-09-10 15:24:34.604 10528-11042/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0b1a540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0b0f5b0)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.614 2621-3201/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0b1a5a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0b0f720)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.672 10672-19265/? W/ctxmgr: [AclManager] No 3 for (accnt=account#-517948760#, com.google.android.gms(10096):UserVelocityProducer, vrsn=19056049, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null ,  pid = 10672). Was: 3 for 1, account#-517948760# [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]

2019-09-10 15:24:34.676 1808-2056/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

2019-09-10 15:24:34.689 2018-2086/? I/WifiService: acquireWifiLock uid=10096 lockMode=2

2019-09-10 15:24:34.692 21888-21931/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.692 21888-21931/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.686 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:101): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6938 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0

2019-09-10 15:24:34.714 21888-21931/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so

2019-09-10 15:24:34.745 10672-10672/? I/GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=com.google.android.gms]

2019-09-10 15:24:34.746 10672-10672/? I/GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=com.google.android.gms]

2019-09-10 15:24:34.760 10672-19265/? I/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl] updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7 [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]

2019-09-10 15:24:34.762 10672-19056/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.762 10672-21932/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: [anon] Changed inference mode: 0

2019-09-10 15:24:34.835 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/essthecelebrit: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.835 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/essthecelebrit: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.866 10672-10672/? E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter

2019-09-10 15:24:34.866 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: BLE 'KK+' software access layer enabled

2019-09-10 15:24:34.872 2018-2968/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143474837 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:34.893 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

2019-09-10 15:24:34.897 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.posh24.se not permitted

2019-09-10 15:24:34.897 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:124)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:86)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.898 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21937/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:166)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)

2019-09-10 15:24:34.900 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2019-09-10 15:24:34.919 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: Client requested scan, settings=BleSettings [scanMode=ZERO_POWER, callbackType=ALL_MATCHES, reportDelayMillis=0, 1 filters, 0 clients, callingClientName=Places]
2019-09-10 15:24:34.920 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: Scan : No clients left, canceling alarm.

2019-09-10 15:24:34.920 10672-10672/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places

2019-09-10 15:24:34.921 10672-10672/? W/Places: BLE failure while scanning - code 5

2019-09-10 15:24:34.976 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

2019-09-10 15:24:34.992 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0

2019-09-10 15:24:34.992 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xebbeee60: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3

2019-09-10 15:24:34.996 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbeee60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebbff4b0)

2019-09-10 15:24:35.001 2018-2979/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143474540 duration=-1568134129665

2019-09-10 15:24:35.002 1792-5477/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496

2019-09-10 15:24:35.010 1678-1678/? I/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@3.0::IMapper/default in either framework or device manifest.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.010 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported

2019-09-10 15:24:35.013 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000

2019-09-10 15:24:35.013 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff803000 size 0x2000

2019-09-10 15:24:35.014 1792-5477/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496

2019-09-10 15:24:35.028 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbeee60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebbff4b0)

2019-09-10 15:24:35.029 21888-21927/com.example.guessthecelebrity D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.119 10528-10561/? W/SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.119 10528-21893/? I/PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[221839864954] from persistence.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.329 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143474882 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.332 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143475329 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.334 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143475332 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.336 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143475335 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.344 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10100 pkg com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox code 79 time=1568141233464 duration=-1568118254536

2019-09-10 15:24:35.539 2018-2116/? D/WificondControl: Scan result ready event

2019-09-10 15:24:35.553 2018-2086/? I/WifiService: releaseWifiLock uid=10096

2019-09-10 15:24:35.561 10672-21932/? I/Places: Converted 1 out of 1 WiFi scans

2019-09-10 15:24:35.565 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143475336 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.567 10672-21932/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: [anon] Changed inference mode: 1

2019-09-10 15:24:35.567 10672-21934/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.567 10672-21421/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.568 2018-2086/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143475001 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:35.590 10672-19056/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: No beacon scan available - ignoring candidates.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.592 10672-21933/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:35.646 2018-2979/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10100 pkg com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox code 41 time=1568143474653 duration=-1

2019-09-10 15:24:36.477 2018-2979/? D/AlarmManagerService: Kernel timezone updated to 240 minutes west of GMT

2019-09-10 15:24:39.997 2018-2086/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143475568 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:40.161 2018-2979/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143475565 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:40.162 10672-21421/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:40.166 2018-2979/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143480161 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:40.182 10672-21932/? I/Places: ?: PlacesBleScanner stop()

2019-09-10 15:24:40.182 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: Scan : No clients left, canceling alarm.

2019-09-10 15:24:40.187 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: Scan canceled successfully.

2019-09-10 15:24:40.194 10672-21932/? I/PlaceInferenceEngine: [anon] Changed inference mode: 0

2019-09-10 15:24:40.213 10672-21935/? I/Places: ?: Couldn't find platform key file.

2019-09-10 15:24:40.224 10672-10672/? I/GeofencerStateMachine: removeGeofences: removeRequest=RemoveGeofencingRequest[REMOVE_BY_PENDING_INTENT pendingIntent=PendingIntent[creatorPackage=com.google.android.gms], packageName=com.google.android.gms]

2019-09-10 15:24:40.740 2018-2968/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143480167 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:40.746 2018-2116/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 79 time=1568143480740 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:24:42.593 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] sad.a(22): Scheduling fallback job with id: 9034, and delay: 43200000 ms

2019-09-10 15:24:42.596 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] sad.a(5): Scheduling fallback in 64799998 (absolute: 74152716)

2019-09-10 15:24:44.654 2018-2044/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

2019-09-10 15:24:44.654 2018-2044/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

2019-09-10 15:24:45.150 10528-10561/? I/WorkerManager: dispose()

2019-09-10 15:24:45.151 10528-10561/? W/ThreadPoolDumper: Queue length for executor EventBus is now 11. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.

2019-09-10 15:24:45.208 10672-10672/? I/BeaconBle: Scan : No clients left, canceling alarm.

2019-09-10 15:24:45.988 2018-2968/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143474540 duration=-1

2019-09-10 15:24:47.597 2621-3566/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api

2019-09-10 15:24:54.703 2018-2044/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

2019-09-10 15:24:54.704 2018-2044/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

2019-09-10 15:24:54.710 2018-2044/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

2019-09-10 15:24:54.710 2018-2044/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

2019-09-10 15:24:56.000 2018-2968/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143490987 duration=0

2019-09-10 15:25:00.018 2176-2442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xebbfe460: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xebc21c60)

2019-09-10 15:25:00.665 1954-1954/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument

2019-09-10 15:25:00.666 1954-1954/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument

2019-09-10 15:25:00.667 14109-21650/? I/Finsky: [946] sby.a(7): Jobs in database: 1-1337 3-4 12-1 24-77777777 26-1414141414

2019-09-10 15:25:00.673 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] sao.handleMessage(102): RunningQueue size: 0, PendingQueue size: 0

2019-09-10 15:25:00.687 14109-14109/? W/Finsky: [2] scz.run(5): No real network when expected

2019-09-10 15:25:00.689 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] rze.a(59): ConstraintMapping: 24-77777777,  -> L: 0ms, D: 58239177ms, C: false, I: true, N: 0

2019-09-10 15:25:00.689 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] rze.a(59): ConstraintMapping: 1-1337, 12-1,  -> L: 0ms, D: 52367136ms, C: false, I: false, N: 1

2019-09-10 15:25:00.690 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] rze.a(59): ConstraintMapping: 3-4,  -> L: 0ms, D: 61832241ms, C: true, I: true, N: 2

2019-09-10 15:25:00.694 14109-14109/? I/Finsky: [2] sbh.a(15): No real network when expected for job 9003. Delaying: 1800000

2019-09-10 15:25:12.013 2018-2572/? W/AppOps: Noting op not finished: uid 10096 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1568143507009 duration=0

Comment: It would be nice to see stacktrace of this error.

Comment: Not really sure what a stacktrace is, but i added my Logcat

Comment: Next time, share the file as link and not the content as post ahah

Answer (score 1):

Stacktrace is part of the logs which tells you what exception has been thrown and lists all classes and methods which have been executed leading to this exception. You logs contain:

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.posh24.se not permitted
 at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:124)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
 at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:86)
```

You're getting `IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.posh24.se not permitted` in line `86` of `MainActivity.java` which is a result of Android policy. To bypass it try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <application
     ...
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     ...>

 </application>
```

More info: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Another possible solution:
Instead of connecting to `http://...` try `https://...`

There's also another problem in your code. You're getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
2019-09-10 15:24:34.899 21888-21888/com.example.guessthecelebrity W/System.err: at com.example.guessthecelebrity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:166)
```

You're trying to `result.split("<div class=\"listedArticles\">");` but downloading failed so you're trying to split non-existing result. That's why it fails.

Comment: Adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" worked perfectly, thank you so much!